# How to increase or decrease a path and keep the value of the stroke

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, resize, stroke

If I draw a path with a stroke (e.g. 3pt) and then want to scale it down to fit, the line value stays the same, how do I scale it up/down and have the stroke adjust automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the item and then open the *Transform Panel* (**Window → Transform** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>)

Now toggle on/off **Scale Strokes & Effects** (this will leave the stroke width the same while scaling)

[image]

---

Scale Strokes & Effects **ON**:

[image: Toggled on]

<sup>▲ Stays the same size (relatively)</sup>

Scale Strokes & Effects **OFF**:

[image: Toggled off]

<sup>▲ Stays the same size (absolutely)</sup>